# Output of du command

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal

I have a folder and it is `16.91GB` in size(I checked in Finder).

I tried to check the size by using `du` command.

So, I tried `du -sh ~/folder` and I got `16G`.

I thought I will get the output in Bytes and convert it. But I don't understand the metric when `-h` is not given.

```
du -s ~/folder
```

Gives `33041320`.  I thought it is in bytes but I'm wrong. In which format it is in?

How can I get `16.91GB` instead of `16G`?

**Note:** I believe the behaviour is same in linux also, so I tagged `linux`. If it's wrong, let me know or remove the tag please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In which format is `33041320` ?
   `33041320` is the number of 512-byte blocks. From man page:

   ```
   If the environment variable BLOCKSIZE is set, and the -k option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in units of that size block. 
   If BLOCKSIZE is not set, and the -k option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in 512-byte blocks.
   ```
2. how do I get 16.91 instead of 16?
   seems that you cannot. The reason why `finder` reports 16.91 is that finder treats 1000 bytes as 1k. so technically speaking, the figure reported by finder is incorrect.  `33041320*512/1000/1000/1000=16.91`

Comment: So if I do `33041320 * 512` I get `16917155840` bytes( Am I correct?). Which is `15.755GB`. I'm getting `1.16GB` less. Is there any command from which I can get exact value of `16.91GB`?

Comment: @SkrewEverything Technically speaking, `16.91` is incorrect. reason is that `finder` treats 1000 bytes as 1k (starting from Snow Leopard). `33041320*512/1000/1000/1000=16.91`

Comment: du --si  gives you the size in linux.  If you are wanting to calculate it above, use 33041320 * 500 (because 500 * 2 = 1000, while 512 * 2 = 1024)